# Understanding Java syntax of GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

Tags: java, android

In the android tutorials, The [GridView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) to be exact, there is a line of code

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
```

Which looks to be declaring/instantiating a GridView object named, gridview and assigning from ...
(GridView)

Now is the (GridView) in parens, the expected return type of findViewById or is it telling where to find `findViewById` since that doesn't appear to be connected to an object (although, it would appear to be a member function of a GridView object)??

I believe that the [findViewById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29) returns an object of type GridView specified by the resource  id of gridview (that we specied in main.xml) and probably now exists after we, earlier, called `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

So, what is being specified with the `(GridView)` part of the syntax and what is specifically meant by the parenthesis?

Comment: in two words it's a class cast

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`findViewById` returns a `View`, which is an abstract base class for all of Android's UI. `GridView` inherits from other views that eventually inherit from `View`. So `findViewById` will take the ID you pass it and return the associated view as a `View`. The `(GridView)` casts the `View` to a `GridView`, allowing you to use the additional functionality of the `GridView` class.

You would receive a `ClassCastException` if you tried to cast the result to something other than a `GridView` or one of `GridView`'s super classes.